# If the derivative tends to $0$ at infinity, does the function have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show that if $f$ is derivable on $\mathbb R$ and if $\lim_{x\to \infty }f'(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)$ exist.

By the mean value theorem, there is an $c_x\in]x,x+1[$ such that $$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c_x).$$

Then $$\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x+1)-f(x)=0.$$

Now, I tried to suppose that $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ doesn't exist, but I can't conclude. Any idea ?

**ADDED**
I accept either the limit as $\pm \infty $ or $\ell\in\mathbb R$. And secondly, can we add a condition on $f$ or $f'$ such that there is an $\ell\in\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=\ell$ ?

Comment: This is "very far from being" true since there exists some smooth functions $f$ such that $f'(x)\to0$ when $x\to\infty$ and yet, $f(x)$ has no limit at infinity in the sense that $$\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty\qquad\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty.$$ For some specific examples, one can try $$f(x)=x^a\sin(x^b)$$ when $x$ is large, for some suitable $(a,b)$.

Comment: Why the "ADDED" paragraph if you accept an answer such that the limit is $+\infty$?

Comment: Because as you said, it was the first question, and principale-ideal-domain answered to it.

Comment: No, at the time it was not. Whatever.

Comment: Just about all you can say for sure about the asymptotic behavior of $f$ is that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not true. Consider $\ln(x)$. The logarithm becomes arbitrary large when the argument approaches infinity but we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}=0.$$

**Edit:** If you want a function which is defined on the whole real line and if you allow $\infty$ as limit take
$$f(x):=\ln(x^2+1)\sin(\ln(x^2+1)).$$
We still have here $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist (and is also not one of $\pm \infty$).

Comment: It may be that OP is allowing $\infty$ as a limit. And a less important point: $\log$ isn't even defined on all of $\bf R$, much less differentiable.

Comment: A simpler example might have been $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$, but I agree with your idea.

Comment: @mickep My original example was wrong because the derivative was unbounded.

Comment: @mickep For your $f$ we still have $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: I never said antything else, I just wanted to give a simpler example defined on all of $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @mickep What do you think about my new edit?

Comment: You can take only $\sin(\log(1+x^{2}))$, it still works.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Absolutely. I kind of tried to make the function restricted on an interval $(a,\infty)$ surjective. In your case the image is $[-1,1]$ which solves the problem as well.