# If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded $C^\infty$ function with $f'(x)\rightarrow 0$, then is $f(x)\rightarrow L$ true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Tonight one of my friends arrived telling me about something he thought this afternoon. We are master students in mathematics and we couldn't answer this question.

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded $C^\infty$ function with $f'(x)\rightarrow 0$, then is $f(x)\rightarrow L$ true, for some $L\in \mathbb{R}$?

It looks a very interesting question and we guess the answer is *yes*. After a while and some attempts with using the MVT, we asked to a professor in the department that couldn't answer as well.

We'll be very glad if somebody could tell something about this problem towards its solution.

Comment: " C∞ limited", what is that?

"f(x)→L" -- as $x$ tends to what?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436094/if-the-derivative-tends-to-0-at-infinity-does-the-function-have-a-limit

Comment: I changed “limited” into “bounded”, as this is the common te rm in English. See https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Função_limitada and the corresponding English page.

Answer (score 0):

No, let $f(x) = \log x$. This function is unbounded as $x\to\infty$ but $f'(x)={1\over x}\to 0$. If you care about it being smooth everywhere without having to appeal to nice concepts like bump functions you can do $\log(x^2+1)$. And for a bounded one try $\sin(\log(x^2+1))$.

Comment: That's not defined on the whole real line...

Comment: Although you could modify it to $f(x)=\ln(x^2+1)\sin(\ln(x^2+1))$, which would be a counter-example as well.

Comment: @u1571372 doesn't matter, you can use a bump function and extend to the left, it won't change the end behavior.

Comment: @u1571372 yeah, or something like that, I just picked a simple example since I can mess with it however I want on the left, all that matters is the end behavior.

Comment: How do you do that maintaining the smooth property?

Comment: Or just take $f(x) = \log(x^2+1)$.

Comment: The function is bounded. An unbounded function can't be a counterexample.

Comment: @u1571372 bump functions and partitions of unity let you glue together two smooth functions in a smooth way, that's what I'm getting at. Henning also has a good example, lots of choices.

Comment: @egreg are you saying that is what "limited" means?

Comment: For a _bounded_ function consider $f(x)=\sin\log(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @AdamHughes It is a common false friend for Romance languages. In Italian “bounded” is “limitato”. See https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Função_limitada for Portuguese (the OP's mother language).

Comment: @egreg thanks a lot, I appreciate the info!